# Safari AutoFill disable

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm currently trying to disable the autofill feature in Safari through CSS, with SO help in previous questions it wasn't to hard to disable the icon, but the autofill recommendation box is still showing when I'm inserting an address:
[image]
So as you can see the highlight section is what I need to remove since it appears on top of my google autocomplete box. I've also tried changing the z-index of the pac-container to see if it could have a higher priority than Safari autofill but it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you show some code? Depending on the circumstances, it might be as easy as adding `autocomplete="off"`.

Comment: The autocomplete="off" is set both at the form tag and the input:
<input type="text" name="location" class="input autocomplete" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder=" " autocomplete="off" id="location">

Comment: Can you edit the question and put that in? Vital information like that should always be in the question itself rather than in comments.

Comment: I'm having essentially the same issue, though in my case, it's not the appearance of a dropdown - it's a noticeable form performance slow-down.  When I go into the Safari prefs and turn off autofill, everything is zippy... I'd just like to do that in the page source instead of rely on the user to change their prefs...